# No type named value_type in boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, qt, vector, stl, tuples

I am trying to create a vector of tuples, and then return this vector out of a function, but I am getting a large number of errors that seem that they have to do with my passing of a pcl::PointCloudColorHandler as an argument into the tuples.  Specifically, the relevant error is:

```
error: no type named 'value_type' in 'boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >'
```

My question is, why is this behavior not allowed? Here is my code:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr>, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > Map::getCloudColoredReal(){
  std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > changed_clouds;
  try{
    for(int i = 0; i < addedFiles.size(); i++){
      if(associatedClouds.find(addedFiles[i].getPCDFileName()) != associatedClouds.end()){
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud(associatedClouds.find(addedFiles[i].getPCDFileName())->second);
        pcl::PointCloud<PointXYZRGBAI> cloudInfo(masterClouds.find(addedFiles[i].getPCDFileName())->second);
        for(int j = 0; j < cloud.points.size(); j++){
          uint32_t red = (cloudInfo.points[j].rgba >> 16) & (0x0000ff);
          uint32_t green = (cloudInfo.points[j].rgba >> 8) & (0x0000ff);
          uint32_t blue = (cloudInfo.points[j].rgba) & (0x0000ff);
          cloud.points[j].r = red;
          cloud.points[j].g = green;
          cloud.points[j].b = blue;
        }
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr constCloud(&cloud);
        pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField::Ptr rgbHandler(&constCloud);
        std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > tup = std::make_tuple(addedFiles[i].getPCDFileName(), constCloud, &rgbHandler);
        changed_clouds.push_back(tup);
      }
    }
  }
  catch(std::exception& e){
    std::cout << "Color Mode not set to real." << std::endl;
  }
  return changed_clouds;
}
```

Full error:

```
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.h:5:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/QVTKWidget.h:39:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkGUISupportQtModule.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkInteractionStyleModule.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkRenderingCoreModule.h:40:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkAutoInit.h:18:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkDebugLeaksManager.h:26:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkSystemIncludes.h:36:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/vtkIOStream.h:28:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iostream:38:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ios:216:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/__locale:15:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:628:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/memory:1456:38: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >'
    typedef typename allocator_type::value_type value_type;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:337:22: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::allocator_traits<boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >' requested here
    typedef typename __alloc_traits::size_type       size_type;
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:458:15: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >' requested here
    : private __vector_base<_Tp, _Allocator>
              ^
/Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.cpp:56:196: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >' requested here
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > > clouds_in_map = m_maps.at(i).getCloudColoredReal();
                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.h:5:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/QVTKWidget.h:40:
In file included from /usr/local/include/vtk-7.0/QVTKInteractor.h:43:
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/Qt5/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/QObject:1:
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/Qt5/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qobject.h:54:
In file included from /Users/wfehrnstrom/Qt5/5.7/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Headers/qmetatype.h:55:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:467:30: error: '__alloc_traits' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::__alloc_traits          __alloc_traits;
                             ^
/Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/dataViewerWidget.cpp:56:196: note: in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::vector<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >' requested here
            std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > > clouds_in_map = m_maps.at(i).getCloudColoredReal();
                                                                                                                                                                                                   ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:334:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef allocator_traits<allocator_type>         __alloc_traits;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:468:30: error: 'reference' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::reference               reference;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:335:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef value_type&                              reference;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:469:30: error: 'const_reference' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::const_reference         const_reference;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:336:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef const value_type&                        const_reference;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:470:30: error: 'size_type' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::size_type               size_type;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:337:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef typename __alloc_traits::size_type       size_type;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:471:30: error: 'difference_type' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::difference_type         difference_type;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:338:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef typename __alloc_traits::difference_type difference_type;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:472:30: error: 'pointer' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::pointer                 pointer;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:339:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef typename __alloc_traits::pointer         pointer;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:473:30: error: 'const_pointer' is a protected member of 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >, boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> > >'
    typedef typename __base::const_pointer           const_pointer;
                             ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:340:54: note: declared protected here
    typedef typename __alloc_traits::const_pointer   const_pointer;
                                                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:479:53: error: no type named 'value_type' in 'boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >'
    static_assert((is_same<typename allocator_type::value_type, value_type>::value),
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
9 errors generated.
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try to reduce the problem, e.g. experiment with vectors of tuples. The not shown instantiation code (with `clouds_in_map`) may be relevant. I don't see anything here, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are missing or put in a wrong position right angle brackets:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr >, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > 
                                                                                ^ - wrong place for bracket
```

should be changed to

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > > 
                                                                                                                                                             ^
```

and

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr > >
                                                                                                                                                  missing ? -^
```